# Problem getting emacs to recognize mix of python and html code

Tags: python, html, django, emacs

I started working on "Django 1.0 Web Site Development" and have gotten my server to work, but when I'm editing my views.py file, I have a difficulty editing the python code in emacs.

The problem seems to be a line that contains the triple quotes ('''):

```
def main_page(request):
  output = u'''
    <html>
    [more lines here]
    </html>
  ''' % (
    u'Django Bookmarks'
    u'Welcome to Django Bookmarks',
    u'Where you can store and share bookmarks!'
  )
  return HttpResponse(output)
```

Emacs identation gets all screwed up after the u''' line and thus I get errors when I try to load the page that is generated from this.

I've tried several modes (including a nxhtml mumamo mode), but so far I can get Emacs to recognize only python code or only html, but not both at the same time.  Short of editing the file as raw text and manipulating the tabs myself, is there another way/

Comment: python-mode.el (version 5.1.0) with GNU Emacs 23.1.50.1 seems to handle triple quotes and indentation without a problem. What version of emacs and python-mode.el or python.el are you using?

Comment: I wouldn't worry to much about it: that's not how you display html in Django. You use separate template files. If it has more than a few examples of that style, I would dump the book and get a better one.

Comment: emacs is 23.1.1    [edit]: I'm not sure how to check the version of python-mode

Comment: @aeroegnr: I looked inside /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/python-mode/python-mode.el to find the version of python-mode. It's location depends on your OS and how it was installed.

Comment: @aeroegnr: It would also be helpful if you explain what keypresses you've tried, what you expected to happen, and what happened instead.

Comment: Okay I that directory didn't contain a python_mode.el or a python.el   The command I am using is either M-x python-mode or it automatically recognizing files with the .py extension with the default install.  I also tried C-c C-v which according to one site was supposed to display the version, but I got nothing.  The book starts to show html templates files later on, so it may not be worth the effort to fix.

Comment: Could you supply the errors that you are receiving so that we can help diagnose them? HTML does not care about indentation at all, and Python only cares about indentation at the start of a line, which happens only three times in the listing you have shown: the first line needs to be flush-left, and the word "output" and the word "return" should each be the same number of spaces in (typically four, but 2 should also work like you have shown) from the left edge. So I do not see anything here that would cause an error; please show us the message! :-)

Comment: Ok, the issue seems to be that when I try to indent the return line, emacs places it at flush left instead of indenting it.  Aside from forcing an indent by switching out of python mode, I'm not sure how to fix it.  The code on the website when I view it is: 'return' outside function (views.py, line 16)           This is as expected with the return not indented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the hint.

You're doing it wrong.  Get to the templates business in chapter 3 before even thinking about tools to support what you're doing.

Stop trying to embed HTML in your view functions and you'll find that emacs is no longer confused.  Move as quickly as possible to the next chapter.  Stop messing with emacs and get going on learning Django.  Move further forward in the book.

But HTML in template files which are almost pure HTML with a few extra `{{variable}}` and `{% tag %}` things thrown around.

You don't have an "emacs formatting" problem.

You have a "using Django incorrectly" problem.

Comment: Okay, well that is code straight from the book I am using to try to learn the framework.

Comment: Why aren't you starting with the Django tutorial on the Django web site?

Comment: I suppose I'll just do that then, sounds like a much better idea.